# How to get all Stock list company name and symbol of NSE and BSE with free API?

Tags: android, json, web-services, yahoo-finance

Hello I am going to develop app for show data from stockmarket.
Yahoo and Google only gives details of specific Symbol data but I need all company list with symbols or ID  which  covers in NSE/BSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below link

http://www.barchartondemand.com/freemarketdataapi.php

or you can can the following they are free, they generate Json, though for different exchanges you need to ensure that correct syntax is used. even Yahoo finance works well, but it has some issues regarding NSE and BSE data, which is always generated Null

Google Finance - NSE

URL - http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:AIAENG,ATULAUTO,

Google Finance - BSE

URL -http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=BOM:524091,532683,

Other Data Feeds (Json)

URL - http://live-nse.herokuapp.com/?symbol=AIAENG,ATULAUTO,

Python Utility (NSE)

URL - http://nsetools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks for answer but i need all symbol list with company name your all above service are useful for only get details of specific stock.

Comment: All stock data like https://in.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/stocks?s=%5e&t=S&m=ALL&r=&b=20

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for? [Quandl BSE ticker list](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quandl-static-content/BSE%20Descriptions/stocks.txt)

This is from  the Quandl page for BSE (https://www.quandl.com/data/BSE). Look at the Documentation tab to get the symbols list. Of course that does not include delisted symbols or symbol changes.

Similarly https://www.quandl.com/data/NSE